# Brewing Low ABV Lager

Tags: first-time-brewer, brewing, lager, alcohol-content

Good day!

My question is simple, me and the wife love lager, I like a good 5% ABV but the wife is a light weight and likes a 3.5% ABV so the question is:

How can I brew a nice lager (similar to Heineken!) that is between 3.8% and 4%?

I have just finished brewing my first ever lager and it has a 4.45% ABV!

Comment: Now what do you want, a nice lager or something similar to Heineken? ;-P

Comment: @Robert I know..... I am a sucker for Heinekken! what about Boston's Sam Adams?

Comment: You could give her a Dutch portion (25 cl), and you yourself could drink a Belgian portion (33 cl) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many websites can provide recipes.  Take a look at some other posts like :

[Recipe websites catering to beginners?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/recipe-websites-catering-to-beginners)

But since you already have a recipe, you just need to lower the ABV a little, take a look here:

[Low ABV stout recipe](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/22110/low-abv-stout-recipe)

Basically, you can add just add little more water (15% to 25%) to your recipe to achieve lower ABV.